# Google Play Console subscription Percentage discount offer

Tags: android, in-app-subscription, discount

Adding a discount offer to the yearly subscription doesn't seem to be working. The billing dialog still shows the full price.

I have set up a yearly subscription. I want to give new subscribers a 20% discount as a new years special. I have added the "Percentage discount" offer, which should run after the free trial. I plan on de-activating the discount offer once the special ends. However, when it is activated and I test it, it still shows as $99.99 instead of $79.99.

I am testing using a google account that has been added to the internal testing track, and this user has never subscribed.

[image: Shows 99.99, I was expecting 79.99]

[image: Two offers for new subscribers. Free trial followed by the discount]

[image: I have applied the 20% discount here]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: just mention this issue to google and let me know what they suggested...